# Events on multiple shapes n KIneticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I want to replicate something like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedSkillsDiagram/. I have attached events in same way in a loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++){

var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
// ..
});

var circle_outer = new Kinetic.Circle({
  // ..
});

layer.add(circle_outer);
layer.add(arc);

arc.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  // ..
});
arc.on('mouseout', function(evt) {
 // ..
});
}

stage.add(layer);
```

I have achieved http://jsfiddle.net/rohitrox/hnuf9/6/

My problem is the hover effect is working only on the inner most arc, as you can see in the fiddle.

Any Idea how to get through this? And I also feel that KineticJs performs slower. Is it? or I am doing it in wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue (I believe) has to do with variable scoping (in JavaScript) which I have faced before. I simply moved your code inside the For Loop outside as a function where the variable 'i' is now local and stays with the objects defined with that function call.

```
 function insideFor(i){
   var data_value = data_array[i].value;

$('#legends').append('<div><span style="background: '+data_array[i].color+';"></span>'+data_array[i].data+'</div>')

var endAngle = startAngle + value_to_angle(data_value);

var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
  drawFunc: function(canvas) {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, this.getAttrs().radius, this.getAttrs().startAngle, this.getAttrs().endAngle, false);
      canvas.stroke(this);
  },
  fill: data_array[i].color,
  stroke: data_array[i].color,
  radius: radius,
  startAngle: startAngle*0.0174532925,
  endAngle: endAngle*0.0174532925,
  strokeWidth: 20
  });

startAngle = endAngle;

var circle_outer = new Kinetic.Shape({
  drawFunc: function(canvas) {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, this.getAttrs().radius, this.getAttrs().startAngle, this.getAttrs().endAngle, false);
      canvas.stroke(this);
  },
  fill: '#ddd',
  stroke: '#ddd',
  radius: radius,
  startAngle: 0,
  endAngle: 360*0.0174532925,
  strokeWidth: 20
});

layer.add(circle_outer);
layer.add(arc);

circle_outer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  (new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: arc, 
  strokeWidth: 25,
  easing: Kinetic.Easings['ElasticEaseInOut']
  })).play();
});
circle_outer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
  (new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: arc, 
  strokeWidth: 20,
  easing: Kinetic.Easings['ElasticEaseInOut']
  })).play();
});

radius -= 30;
stage.add(layer);
}

  for(var i = 0; i < data_array.length; i++){
    insideFor(i);

  }
```

Here is the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hnuf9/7/

Comment: :) It was maddening for me when I first got stuck with it